# How to move a directory in Python?

Tags: python

I need to move a directory from one location to another location on the same filesystem.  I'm aware of solutions like `shutil.move()`, but the filesystem in question is an SD card (and therefore extremely slow), and there are a lot of files to move, so simply copying them and then deleting the originals is not acceptable.  The Unix `mv` command can move a directory from one filesystem to the same filesystem without copying any files -- is there a way to do that in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the answer is yes.  As you probably know, you can move a file (assuming it doesn't already exist in the destination) using `os.rename(r'D:\path1\myfile.txt', r'D:\path2\myfile.txt')`.  You can do the same for directories:

```py
os.rename(r'D:\long\path\to\mydir', r'D:\mydir')
```

but, of course, that only works if D:\mydir doesn't already exist.  If it does exist, and you want to merge the files that are already there with the files that you're moving, you'll need to get a little bit more clever.  Here's a snippet that'll do what you want:

```py
def movedir(src, dst):
    try:
        os.rename(src, dst)
        return
    except FileExistsError:
        pass
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src):
        dest_root = os.path.join(dst, os.path.relpath(root, src))
        done = []
        for dir_ in dirs:
            try:
                os.rename(os.path.join(root, dir_), os.path.join(dest_root, dir_))
                done.append(dir_)
            except FileExistsError:
                pass
        for dir_ in done:
            dirs.remove(dir_)
        for file in files:
            os.replace(os.path.join(root, file), os.path.join(dest_root, file))
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src, topdown=False):
        os.rmdir(root)
```

Here's a version with comments explaining what everything does:

```py
def movedir(src, dst):
    # if a directory of the same name does not exist in the destination, we can simply rename the directory
    # to a different path, and it will be moved -- it will disappear from the source path and appear in the destination
    # path instantaneously, without any files being copied.
    try:
        os.rename(src, dst)
        return
    except FileExistsError:
        # if a directory of the same name already exists, we must merge them.  This is what the algorithm below does.
        pass
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src):
        dest_root = os.path.join(dst, os.path.relpath(root, src))
        done = []
        for dir_ in dirs:
            try:
                os.rename(os.path.join(root, dir_), os.path.join(dest_root, dir_))
                done.append(dir_)
            except FileExistsError:
                pass
        # tell os.walk() not to recurse into subdirectories we've already moved.  see the documentation on os.walk()
        # for why this works: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk
        # lists can't be modified during iteration, so we have to put all the items we want to remove from the list
        # into a second list, and then remove them after the loop.
        for dir_ in done:
            dirs.remove(dir_)
        # move files.  os.replace() is a bit like os.rename() but if there's an existing file in the destination with
        # the same name, it will be deleted and replaced with the source file without prompting the user.  It doesn't
        # work on directories, so we only use it for files.
        # You may want to change this to os.rename() and surround it with a try/except FileExistsError if you
        # want to prompt the user to overwrite files.
        for file in files:
            os.replace(os.path.join(root, file), os.path.join(dest_root, file))
    # clean up after ourselves.
    # Directories we were able to successfully move just by renaming them (directories that didn't exist in the
    # destination already) have already disappeared from the source.  Directories we had to merge are still there in
    # the source, but their contents were moved.  os.rmdir() will fail unless the directory is already empty.
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src, topdown=False):
        os.rmdir(root)

movedir(r'D:\long\path\to\mydir', r'D:\mydir')
```

Please note that using os.rename() in this manner only works if the source path and the destination path are on the same filesystem (on Windows, this is true if they have the same drive letter).  If they're on different drive letters (i.e. one is on C: and the other is on D:) or if one of the paths contains a reparse point (if you don't know what that is, don't worry about it, you'll probably never encounter one), you will need to use `shutil.move()`, which copies the files and then deletes them from the source -- this what Windows does when you move files between drives, and it takes about as long to finish.